# Do Indian citizens living in USA and having a Green Card need a visa to visit Australia and New Zealand as a tourist?

Tags: tourist-visas

Do Indian citizens living in the USA and having a Green Card for more than 10 years need a visa to visit Australia and New Zealand as a tourist for about 10 days in each country?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Your question would be strengthened if you could [edit] it to indicate what research you have already attempted in this matter, as this is one of the expectations of Stack Exchange. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Australia offers ETA for citizens of several countries, including the US, but not including India.  Having permanent residence in one of those countries does not suffice; [you must have a passport issued by a qualifying country](https://www.eta.immi.gov.au/ETAS3/etas).

Australia also offers eVisitor for citizens of several countries, [not including India](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/651-#tab-content-1), so that also won't help.  You therefore need a visa for Australia.

New Zealand offers a visa waiver for citizens of several countries, including the United States, but not including India.  Eligibility depends on being a *citizen* of one of the [visa waiver countries](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/visa-waiver-countries).  US non-citizen nationals are included, but not permanent residents.  You therefore need a visa for New Zealand.

You can qualify for the programs mentioned above if you naturalize in the US and travel with a US passport.